# How to find a parent with a known class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, parent

I have a `<div>` that has many other `<div>`s within it, each at a different nesting level. Rather than give every child `<div>` an identifier, I rather just give the root `<div>` the identifier. Here’s an example:

```
<div class="a" id="a5">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <a class="d">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I write a function in jQuery to respond to class `d` and I want to find the ID for its parent, class `a`, how would I do this?

I cannot simply do `$('.a').attr('id');`, because there are multiple class `a`s. I could find its parent’s parent’s parent’s ID but that seems of poor design, slow, and not very polymorphic (I would have to write different code for finding the ID for class `c`).

Answer (score 685, accepted):

Assuming that `this` is `.d`, you can write

```
$(this).closest('.a');
```

The [`closest` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest) returns the innermost parent of your element that matches the selector.

Comment: Note that there is little catch: If your starting element matches query  too you don't get parent element but same element instead. This may or may not be wanted behaviour. If not, I recomend this:
$(this).parent().closest('.a');

Comment: Very helpful. I always use to do $(this).parent().parent().parent() and i knew there was a better solution.

Answer (score 46):

Pass a selector to the jQuery [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function:

```
d.parents('.a').attr('id')
```

**EDIT** Hmm, actually Slaks's answer is superior if you only want the closest ancestor that matches your selector.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get all parents with the given selector.

> Description: Get the ancestors of each
>   element in the current set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a
>   selector.

But [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) will get just the first parent of the element.

> Description: Get the parent of each
>   element in the current set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a
>   selector.

[jQuery parent() vs. parents()](http://jqueryminute.com/jquery-parent-vs-parents/)

And there is [.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) which I think will be the best.

> Description: Get the ancestors of each
>   element in the current set of matched
>   elements, up to but not including the
>   element matched by the selector.

Comment: He only wants a _single_ parent, so he should call `closest`.

Answer (score 13):

Extracted from @Resord's comments above. This one worked for me and more closely inclined with the question.

```
$(this).parent().closest('.a');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
<div id="412412412" class="input-group date">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Button Click</button>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
</div>
```

In my situation, i use this code:

```
$(this).parent().closest('.date').attr('id')
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Use .parentsUntil()

```
$(".d").parentsUntil(".a");
```

Comment: That would target every parent element until reaching the matched, parent element.