# how do i find the parent for this?

Tags: jquery

im trying to get the parent of this input but it just wont, i get the label at its most. what im i doing wrong?

```
<div class="input req">

            <p>
                <label>                   
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street, new { TABINDEX = 1,data_validate = "required|min[2]" })%>
                </label>
            </p>

            <p class="msg">
            </p>

        </div>
```

JQUERY

```
alert($('#Street').parent('div.input').length);
```

EDIT: i should add this is all work in a  thickbox and i get length 1 if i take `parent('label')`

EDIT2: missed this link that is posted
[How to find a parent with a known class in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333426/how-to-find-a-parent-with-a-known-class-in-jquery)

**-2 minus for what?**

Comment: Please show the generated HTML.

Comment: try and change it to alert($('#Street').parents('div.input').length);

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333426/how-to-find-a-parent-with-a-known-class-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert($('#Street').parents('div.input').length);
                         ^
```

`parent()` will go up one level, on the other hand [**`.parents()`**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) will go up until it matches the selector.

In your case, the immediate parent is the element `p`, not the `div.input`.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('#Street').parents('div.input:first').length);
```

which is similar to :

```
alert($('#Street').closest('div.input').length);
```

parent just look for the immediate parent. You should use one of the above methods instead

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alert($('#Street').closest('div.input').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alert($('#Street').parent('label').parent('p').parent('div.input').length);
```

Parent only looks at the element directy above it, this way you take the steps necessary to climb the DOM tree.