# How to select parent element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

How do I select the parent element of  `<a class="4">` ?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="2">
    <li>
        <a class="4">
    <li>
        <a class="6">
</ul>
```

Something like this?

```
$(".4, li > a").addclass("active");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: What about $("a.4").parent().addClass("active");

Comment: li not closed anywhere??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a parent with a known class in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333426/how-to-find-a-parent-with-a-known-class-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jQuery :

```
$(".4").parent().addclass("active");
```