# target separetly div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I have more than one `<td>` and I click on my button it opens all list in the table, and I don't want that. I want to open it only in the `<tr>` that one specifically.
I don't know how to target it individually only with one javascript code.

Html code:

```
<table class="block-IPs-table" id="block-IPs-table">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td class="widht-400 vertical-align-bottom">
            <div class="menu-toggle-left clearfix pull-right">
              <ul class="toggle-left clearfix">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban active-red fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-toggle btn-left-click" type="button" id=""><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></button>
            </div><!-- menu toggle -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

this is my javascript code:

```
var menuWrapper = $('.menu-toggle-left'),
                     button = menuWrapper.find('.btn-toggle'),
   menu = menuWrapper.find('ul');
   menu.hide()
   $(".btn-toggle").on('click', function(){
      menu.toggle("fast");
   });
```

An image how it looks when I click one:
[image]

Comment: [`$(this)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: instead of `menuWrapper.find('ul');` try using `menuWrapper.closest('ul');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a parent with a known class in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333426/how-to-find-a-parent-with-a-known-class-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To toggle only the ul element within the same parent:

```
$(".btn-toggle").on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest("div").find("ul").toggle("fast");
});
```

That is, navigate through the DOM by starting with the clicked element (`this`), going up to its containing div, then back down to the ul.

In context demo:

```js
$(".btn-toggle").on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest("div").find("ul").toggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="block-IPs-table" id="block-IPs-table">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td class="widht-400 vertical-align-bottom">
            <div class="menu-toggle-left clearfix pull-right">
              <ul class="toggle-left clearfix">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">Item a1<i class="fa fa-ban active-red fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">Item a2<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-toggle btn-left-click" type="button" id=""><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x" aria-hidden="false">Toggle</i></button>
            </div><!-- menu toggle -->
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td class="widht-400 vertical-align-bottom">
            <div class="menu-toggle-left clearfix pull-right">
              <ul class="toggle-left clearfix">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">Item b1<i class="fa fa-ban active-red fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">Item b2<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-toggle btn-left-click" type="button" id=""><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x" aria-hidden="false">Toggle</i></button>
            </div><!-- menu toggle -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```