# Select $this div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to select the "checkbox-group" from `$this` element because in the form I could have many checkbox-group.

Actually I'm doing this in jQuery in order to display an error message.

```
$(document).delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function()
{
    $(".required_custom").remove();

    if(!$(this).prop('required') && !$(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.checkbox-group').after('<br class="required_custom" ><span class="required_custom" style="color:red">Au moins une case doit être coché</span>');
    }
});
```

But with this code I'm displaying this error message to some others checkbox-group.

How can I use the "after" method in order to select only `$this` checkbox-group ?

Thanks in advance. My html look like this with just one checkbox-group in the example but as I said before I could have many others.

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox-group-1547545912597[]" id="checkbox-group-1547545912597-0" aria-required="true" value="1" type="checkbox" class="user-error" required="required" aria-invalid="true">
        <label for="checkbox-group-1547545912597-0">Option 1</label></div><div class="checkbox"><input name="checkbox-group-1547545912597[]" id="checkbox-group-1547545912597-1" aria-required="true" value="2" type="checkbox" required="required">
        <label for="checkbox-group-1547545912597-1">Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a parent with a known class in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333426/how-to-find-a-parent-with-a-known-class-in-jquery)

Comment: You can use the answers to the question in my previous comment to query for a parent of the clicked checkbox (`$(this)`) with the class `checkbox-group` using some thing like `$(this).closest('.checkbox-group')` or `$(this).parents('.checkbox-group')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the parent of `this` using jQuery's `parents()` method:

```
$(this).parents('.checkbox-group').after('<br class="required_custom" ><span class="required_custom" style="color:red">Au moins une case doit être coché</span>');
```

```js
$(document).delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function() {
    $(".required_custom").remove();
    
    if(!$(this).prop('required') && !$(this).is(':checked')){
        
        $(this).parents('.checkbox-group').after('<br class="required_custom" ><span class="required_custom" style="color:red">Au moins une case doit être coché</span>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox-group-1547545912597[]" id="checkbox-group-1547545912597-0" aria-required="true" value="1" type="checkbox" class="user-error" required="required" aria-invalid="true">
        <label for="checkbox-group-1547545912597-0">Option 1</label></div><div class="checkbox"><input name="checkbox-group-1547545912597[]" id="checkbox-group-1547545912597-1" aria-required="true" value="2" type="checkbox" required="required">
        <label for="checkbox-group-1547545912597-1">Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this code here:

```js
$(document).delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function()
{
    

    if(!$(this).prop('required') || !$(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).addClass('error').next('label').addClass('error');
        
    }else {
       $(this).removeClass('error').next('label').removeClass('error');    
    }
});
```

```css
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox-group-1547545912597[]" id="checkbox-group-1547545912597-0" aria-required="true" value="1" type="checkbox" class="user-error" required="required" aria-invalid="true">
        <label for="checkbox-group-1547545912597-0">Option 1</label></div><div class="checkbox">
        
        <input name="checkbox-group-1547545912597[]" id="checkbox-group-1547545912597-1" aria-required="true" value="2" type="checkbox" required="required">
        <label for="checkbox-group-1547545912597-1">Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: code only answers aren't answers IMO - add some explanation so OP can learn the cause/solution and understand it all :)

Comment: this is simple logic when a user click a checkbox then the execute if condition, when if condition true then add a class instant click checkbox otherwise work reverse